# How do you pull an Incident and ServiceRequest's 'Created By User' property?

Tags: powershell, properties

I can't seem to use a good enough combination of words for Google. Everything I find, it's for the effected user, the person this ticket is for. I do not care about this... I am trying to find the agent/person who CREATES the ticket instead! I am trying to pull information of how many incidents and service request tickets my desk has created, and while I can track completed MA's by us, it eludes me on this.

I cannot find any documentation at all on how to do this... The closest I could find, the cmdlets they use are no longer included in SMLets.

Basically, I want to do this https://lazywinadmin.com/2016/03/powershellscsm-get-manual-activities_9.html#, but apply it to created incidents and SRs.

The closest I've found was a Get called `Get-SCSMClassProperty`, but I cannot find any documentation on how to use it. The closest I've found was a bug report where the code is cutoff.

Ultimately, I already have the backbone required to compare a result to a list of agents, I just don't know the actual property name or how to reference it. 
A reference I've tried is: https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/scsm-powershell-get-work-item-information/

But what is suggested, `Get-SCSMClassInstance`, does not exist anymore. But if it did, it yields the below output, which is pretty close to what I am think I am trying to find here.

[image: Screenshot of Get-SCSMClassInstance output]

Comment: From what I'm reading, the command you want "should" be available. Do you get any results from running `Get-Command -module System.Center.Service.Manager`? When I say "should," it means I'm looking at the System Center 2019 documentation.

Comment: I use a different module calle SMlets, I didn't actually know that module existed. I don't think I'm using it right though, as it yields nothing